# Using pytest to test a DRF post

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm searching for some examples to test my drf api with pytest. I made some fixtures to create user and connect. Does someone have a guide/reference to implement a POST test? It is for a product with the following fields: name, description, price and category.

For status_code test I wrote:

```
@pytest.fixture
def user():
    username = 'test'
    password = 'test'
    User.objects.user(username=username, password=password)


@pytest.fixture
@pytest.mark.django_db
def client(user):
    token = Token.objects.get(user__username='test')
    client = APIClient()
    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
    return client


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_status(client):
    resp = client.get('/myapi/api/product/')
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

And it's ok.

For test a product create, I tried this:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create(client):
    resp = client.post(
        '/myapi/api/product/',
            {
                'name': 'teste1',
                'description': "Teste1",
                'price': 3.50,
                'category': 1
            },
        format='json'
    )
    assert resp.status_code == 201
```

But I receive 400.

Comment: Do you have an error message in the response (`resp`) body? Maybe that could include a clue on what is wrong here, for instance it could be the JSON payload itself.

Comment: Hey, @SamuelDion-Girardeau thank you for your answer. I printed the resp using data (print(resp.data)) and I receive some clues.